# Qt app build from cmd-line as a .bat file

Tags: qt, batch-file, jenkins, cmd, auto-build

Am trying to automate a build process of an Qt app from a .bat file.

Am able to build a Qt app from cmd-line by entering each cmd one-by-one. Like ***qtenv2.bat***, then ***vcvars64.bat***, and then ***qmake***.
But when I put those cmd in a .bat file and try to execute the bat in cmd, strange is happening, ie, **after qtenv2.bat runs, it doesn't proceed to the next cmd for vcvar64.bat, it quits the execution**.
The autoBuild.bat file is as below.

[image]

So when I run this in cmd, it's as below **stops after qtenv2.bat**

[image]

***I want it to continue with the next cmds in the same console(it's a necessity for the build process) as below, where I run each cmds step-by-step. And the same is required from the .bat file.***

[image]

I tried the following .... ***start "qtenv2" /min cmd /k call qtenv2.bat***......but it started the process in a separate console, which I don't want.

Any suggestion, how to write the .bat file, so that qtenv2.bat runs and then vcvars.bat also runs in the same console with stopping the execution.

Regards,
Sayan

Comment: Use `call` to run another batch file

Answer (score 0):

Changing between drives blocks your bat file to continue. Just add `/D` in `cd` command should help :

```
@echo "setting up Qt env..."
cd /D C:/a/b/c
qtenv.bat
@echo "going to working dir ..."
cd /D D:/works_dir/
$VC_FULL_PATH/vcvars64.bat
@echo "building now ...."
qmake && make clean
make
```